# Count in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe df with a column "id" (string) and another column "values" (array of strings). I want to create another column called count with contains the count of values for each id.

df looks like -

```
id        values
1fdf67    [dhjy1,jh87w3,89yt5re]
df45l1    [hj098,hg45l0,sass65r4,dh6t21]
```

Result should look like -

```
id        values                          count
1fdf67    [dhjy1,jh87w3,89yt5re]          3
df45l1    [hj098,hg45l0,sass65r4,dh6t21]  4
```

I am trying to do as below -

```
df= df.select(id,values).toDF(id,values,values.count())
```

This doesn't seem to be working for my requirement.

Comment: `values` is not a variable, is it? So, what would `values.count()` give you?

Comment: I think you are looking for the `withColumn()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `size` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import size

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("1fdf67", ["dhjy1", "jh87w3", "89yt5re"]),
    ("df45l1", ["hj098", "hg45l0", "sass65r4", "dh6t21"])],
    ("id", "values"))

df.select("*", size("values").alias("count")).show(2, False)

+------+---------------------------------+-----+
|id    |values                           |count|
+------+---------------------------------+-----+
|1fdf67|[dhjy1, jh87w3, 89yt5re]         |3    |
|df45l1|[hj098, hg45l0, sass65r4, dh6t21]|4    |
+------+---------------------------------+-----+
```